# Type from included header not found

Tags: c, atmelstudio

I have a weird problem with my C-Code that I don't really understand.
I have two header files `os_memory.h` and `os_mem_drivers.h`.

## os_memory.h

```
#ifndef OS_MEMORY_H_
#define OS_MEMORY_H_

#include "lcd.h"
#include "os_mem_drivers.h"

static const MemAddr gui_alloc_table_start = 0x1C8;

#endif /* OS_MEMORY_H_ */
```

## os_mem_drivers.h

```
#ifndef OS_MEM_DRIVERS_H_
#define OS_MEM_DRIVERS_H_

#include "os_memory.h"
#include "defines.h"
#include "os_core.h"

typedef uint16_t MemAddr;

#endif
```

If I try to compile this code the compiler gives me the error `unknown type name 'MemAddr'`. I don't get it because I included the right header files in each .h file so there shouldn't be any error.
Is there anything that I'm missing here?

I'm using AtmelStudio 6.1 and the C language for this project.

Comment: The two headers are circularly including each others. You might like to sort out your interfaces.

Comment: Your header file structure is wrong. Make sure each header file stands on its own. It is bad that header files depend on other header files or that the order of #includes and definitions matter.

Comment: @pmg I'm aware of this and I was a bit distracted that this should be the correct solution according to my exercise papers. Actually I found out that I misread the papers and instead could have put all the things into os_mem_drivers.h right away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should move the definition for type `MemAddr` before including `"os_memory.h"`:

**os_mem_drivers.h**:

```
#ifndef OS_MEM_DRIVERS_H_
#define OS_MEM_DRIVERS_H_

#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint16_t MemAddr;

#include "os_memory.h"
#include "defines.h"
#include "os_core.h"

#endif
```

But a more important problem is the circular inclusion of `"os_memory.h"` and `"os_mem_drivers.h"`.  Each one includes the other: include guards prevent recursive inclusion but make it difficult to understand what is really going on. You should try and fix this issue.